# the package javax.enterprise.context is missing after glassfish update

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, cdi, glassfish-4

this morning I used glassfish update tool to update the server when the process is finished I find that Eclipse can't recognize javax.enterprise.context package (CDI), how can I rollback installed updates??
http://im61.gulfup.com/uqpxlA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delete the server and reinstalle it, now it works, Glassfish 4.1 Bug

Answer (score 1):

`javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` is missing in Glassfish 4.1. It's a bug.

Comment: i use Netbeans 8.0.1  when i declare a new jsf managed bean whith session , it is created whith import javax.entreprise.context.SessionScoped but doesn't exist in the package  and the same code doesn't work

Comment: download this zip: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/Weld/2.2.0.SP1/ (49.7 MB)after you extract it, go to: weld-2.2.0.SP1\artifacts\cdi and add this jar to your project "cdi-api" and it will work, it works for me, but I'm still on glassfish 4.0, let me know if it works