# Downloading and adding javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped to my project

Tags: java, netbeans

I've got a project running 1.7. I'm getting issues using `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`. I'm confused as to why it isn't included as I have other `javax.*` libraries built into Netbeans by default.

Where can I download this library and how can I add it to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the [Java EE Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html). You should start your project within a container. In Netbeans use an Enterprise Application project type.

Comment: I tried doing this and I'm still getting an issue importing `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`. I don't have `javax.enterprise.context`. I only have `concurrent` and `deploy`.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076613/the-package-javax-enterprise-context-is-missing-after-glassfish-update
Also see here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247013

Answer (score 7):

By default, only the packages that are part of the Java Standard Edition are available. This library belongs to Java EE. Just go to project->properties->libraries->add library->Java EE Web 7 Api Library->add. That´s it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
You can import this jar file into your project.

Use `cdi-api.jar`

I found mine in glassfish folder

`.\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\modules`